# How to fix 'error invalid assignment target' vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, quasar

I am building application using Vite and Quasar.
I built a child component and defined the props and data and use them on template.
But have this error: Invalid assignment target

```html
<template>
  <QCheckbox 
    v-model="(data.gps?.enable)" 
    class="q-mt-none" 
    label="GPS Only Tracking Enabled " />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";
  import {defineComponent } from "vue";
  import * as types from "../../../types";
  
  const props = defineProps({
    modalProps: Object as () => types.Itarget
  });
  
  const defaults = {
      gps: props.modalProps?.gps,
  };
  let data = ref(_.cloneDeep(defaults));
</script>
```

Here, "gps" is object like this:
gps: {
enable: true,
perform?: 'Normal',
distance?: 33
}

If I use 'data.gps?.enable' on v-model, error has been occured.
How to fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a value to `data` the component is not already mounted (or beforeMounted), so the component don't know at this moment the value of the props.

you should assign variables only in creation `hooks`

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
    defaults = {
        gps: props.modalProps?.gps,
    };
    data.value = _.cloneDeep(defaults)
})
```

if you want to be more secure you can add a `v-if` in your template and check if the value exists

```
<QCheckbox v-if="data.gps" .... >
```

Even better: default values for props

```
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
    modalProps: Object as () => types.Itarget
}>(), {
    modalProps: { enable: false, perform: '', distance: null }
})
```